# How do I work with MongoDB from ASP.Net web pages and razor?

Tags: c#, mongodb, razor

I've gotten my head around MongoDB syntax using the JSON notation and I can find some C# examples around, but they are more complex than I'd like and I'm looking for a very simple model to follow for doing basic work with Mongo from Web pages and razor.

Comment: Would you be able to be more specific? What sort of basic work do you need to do?

Comment: At this point just basic CRUD examples. A lot of the examples listed like in the answer by @jrummell involve building mappings to local objects, but I'd like to just start by making simple requests and getting back objects that I can work with the way Razor (I guess it is WebMatrix.Data) like:

@foreach(var product in products){
    @product.ProductName<br />
}

Comment: Our project uses RavenDB(another No SQL) with MVC3 and other open source web components (Agathta, Strucuturemap, bootstrapper, etc.) As mentioned before, you better implement Repository pattern and some Infrastructure Framework to set aside CRUD operations, and low level implementations.

Answer (score 3):

You don't. Your data access should be done in your code behind, or even better, a repository that is called by your code behind.

If you do a quick search, you'll see that there are quite a few examples of using MongoDB with .NET.

- http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Language+Center
- http://www.joe-stevens.com/2011/10/02/a-mongodb-tutorial-using-c-and-asp-net-mvc/
- http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/database/3a73c6de-82a1-4690-a7aa-d0eda58203f7/store-aspnet-site-visitor-stats-in-mongodb.aspx

Comment: I fully understand best practices as far as repositories and building local objects go. But I'm specifically asking for the exception. I added some more clarifying details in a comment on the question.

Comment: So you are purposefully ignoring best practice? That doesn't sound like a good idea, even it is only to learn basic CRUD. Why not write a simple Console application instead?